# Invert plus circle font awesome icon colors

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, favicon

I want the font awesome icon as the following image:

[image]

So I try to add that as the following code:

```css
.custom-icon {
  position: relative; 
  color: #a3a1a1;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.custom-icon::before {
  content: '\f067';
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #a3a1a1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.custom-icon::after {
  content: '\f055';
  font-size: inherit;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa-solid fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg custom-icon"></i>
```

But it is not the same as the image, how can I invert the colors, outline the circle, paint the + icon inside the circle and remove color from the circle background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [stack feature](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/style/stack) and merge two icons together

```css
.custom-icon {
  color: #a3a1a1;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="fa-stack custom-icon">
  <i class="fa-regular fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```